# How create a template for a blank page with header, footer and classic reports?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using `Oracle APEX 21.1`. I am developing an app for clinic management. There is a page that should hold the patient's prescription and other data and a header - data displayed on every page at the top and a footer - data displayed at the bottom of every page. All regions in the page are based on classic reports. The page should be printed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> browser command.

I need to create a blank page that has nothing but the classic reports regions. And I need those regions to be displayed each as per to their template. I tried modifying the `Standard` page template by removing many `<div>` elements and classes but the result is not good at all.

Sometimes, the browser displays two pages to print when there is only one. Other times, the classic reports are not displayed correctly. Is there a way to create such a template that has nothing but a header, a footer and classic reports that retain their styling?

```
ws= eslam_ws
un= forhelp
pwd= Forhelppwd$
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to modify the page template to accomplish this.

1 - Create a blank page. Go to properties. Set template to "Minimal (no navigation)".

2 - Create 3 regions:

```
Call the first "Header" go to properties set position to "Breadcrumb Bar".
Call the second "Body" go to properties set position to "Body"
Call the third "Footer" go to properties set position to "Footer".
```

Done. You can put inside these regions whatever you want.

Comment: 1- Doing so did not remove the blue bar at the top of the page which holds the logged in user name and a button to logout. 2- setting header and footer regions in the positions you mentioned did not make them appear in every page to print.

Comment: You can use css to hide this bar. Things you need in every page you should put in the page 0, it is a global page where the regions are displayed in every page of your application. Maybe apex is not what you need for this project.